# Centering a text in longtable

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am having some difficulty with centering a text in a table. If you happen to have some spare time, please kindly enlighten me on the following problem.

Referring to the picture below, you could see that the word "Graph" is left aligned instead of center. How to make it centered? Could you please provide advice or guidance on the issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\tesplot}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=.4,auto=center]
\node (n1) at (10.6,4.9) [draw, circle,fill=green!20] {1};
\node (n2) at (4,0.8) [draw, circle,fill=blue!20] {2};
\node (n3) at (3.8,11.4) [draw, circle,fill=green!20] {3};
\node (n4) at (0.1,6.4) [draw, circle,fill=green!20] {4};
\node (n5) at (3.6,3.4) [draw, circle,fill=blue!20] {5};
\node (n6) at (7.4,2.3) [draw, circle,fill=blue!20] {6};
\node (n7) at (9,10.4) [draw, circle,fill=green!20] {7};
\node (n8) at (18,10.8) [draw, circle,fill=green!20] {8};

\foreach \from/\to in {n6/n2,n2/n5,n5/n6}
\draw[blue] (\from) -- (\to);
\foreach \from/\to in {n1/n8,n8/n7,n7/n1,n3/n7,n4/n3}
\draw[green] (\from) -- (\to);
\foreach \from/\to in {n6/n1,n5/n4,n2/n4,n1/n5}
\draw[red] (\from) -- (\to);

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ l  l  l  l >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{ c }{Convergence} \\
\midrule
Time & \multicolumn{2}{ c }{Information} & Graph & Description \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(l){5-5}
& Vertice & 8 & & \\[1cm] 
1 & ${P(1)}$ & 0.5 & 
\raisebox{-2.3cm}[50pt][50pt]{%
\tesplot} &  \raisebox{-0.1cm}[0pt][0pt]{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{2.8in}
Hello World akdjfasljdfkjasj dfjsadkflkjksad flkaskjdfsadlflkj safdalkjsfd sljdfkjasj         dfjsa sljdfkjasj dfjsadkflkjksad flkaskjd fsadlflkj safdalkjsfd sljdfkjasj dfjsadkflkjksad flkaskjdfsadl flkj safdalkjsfd dkflkjksad flkaskjdfsadlflkj safdalkjsfd
\end{minipage} } {%
} \\[1cm] 
& Chance & 0.5 & & \\[1cm]

\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just encase the header word in question, `Graph`, in its own `\multicolumn` directive: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Graph}`.

Comment: or try `\begin{longtable}{ l  l  l  c >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm} }`

Comment: you might want to do the same with the header for the last column ("Description").

Comment: @Mico -- you should post your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Graph}
```

solved by Mico(https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico), thanks all, thanks a lot!!!!!!